# Host name lookup failure in send mail

Tags: linux, sendmail, lookup, hostname

I am sending mail via Sendmail. But it  gives error in maillog **"Name server: mail.example.com: host name lookup failure."** What might be the problem?

Comment: Well, it **might** be that 'mail.example.com' is not a real name, and so trying to look it up won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really use `mail.example.com` as mail server, that means you are using an incorrect value of SMTP host .

`mail.example.com` is not a valid SMTP server. Do you have a valid SMTP server? If not, try Google's one.

**sidenote:** Not sure if you know that `example.com` is a reserved domain name for documentation purposes and examples of the use of domain names. Read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) for more information.

Comment: Okay. So, what is the correct format to write domain name in the host file in linux? Would it be necessary to use a DNS server? Actually, my intention is not to use it.

Comment: it is your SMTP server address. Contact server admin if you don't know. DNS server is NOT a SMTP server.